# Completion handler was never called?

Tags: ios, block

When this method (`application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`) is done, now how should I call the `completionHandler` block?

As the document describes that "In practice, your app should call the handler block as soon as possible after downloading the needed data."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler 
{
    // Based on the provided meta data in userInfo, load the resource from our 
    // server which corresponds to the "updated" information:

    NSDictionary* params = ; // based on userInfo
    [self fetchInfoWithParams:params completion:^(NSData* result, NSError* error){
        UIBackgroundFetchResult fetchResult;
        if (error) {
            fetchResult = UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed;
        }
        else if (result) {
            fetchResult = UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData;
        }
        else {
            // data is nil
            fetchResult = UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData;
        }

        // call the handler (if any):
        if (handler) {
            handler(fetchResult);
        }
    }];
}
```